# How do I set the test timeout value inside a TFSBuild MSBuild script?

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild

I have an MSBuild script that tells TFSBuild to run my automated tests like the following:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="MyBuild" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
...
<ItemGroup>
    <TestContainer Include="$(OutDir)\Test1.dll" />
    <TestContainer Include="$(OutDir)\Test2.dll" />
    <TestContainer Include="$(OutDir)\Test3.dll" />
    ...
</ItemGroup>
...
```

It seems the default timeout for a test is 30 min, but none of my tests should ever take more than ~3 seconds. How do I change the timeout in the XML?

(I'm using the test framework found in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Built-in test execution functionality in a TFS Build Definition, located on the Process tab of a Build Definition.  It allows you to specify a *.testsettings file, which in turn will contain the timeouts, etc.

Comment: My build process uses a custom MSBuild task. From what I gather, this precludes the possibility of setting a *.testsettings file (or at least setting one in the UI).

Comment: @Mick Why are you using a custom task vs the built in functionality?

Comment: My understanding is that we're running separate batch files after the build process to do things like create/update databases (that ship with the product) and to run a tool to create an installer from the dlls (i.e. running an InstallShield batch file). I inherited this clusterf, so I'm all for doing things in a standard/supported way if at all possible.

Comment: @Mick Well, while I may not be stoked about the batch files, I  understand inheriting them.  Are you saying that the batch files need to be executed prior to the MSTest invocation (i.e. prereq)?  If not, I still don't understand why you can't tell the current TFS Build definition you are using to run the tests for you, bypassing your custom task.  Having said all of that, your custom task is just calling MSTest.exe, which takes a testsettings commandline parameter as well.

Comment: Yes, some processes need to be run prior to the test execution. For example, the database tests require the db schema to be up to date.

Comment: @Mick - Ok, so two things - 1) have you looked how the custom MSBuild task invokes MSTest?  2) You could move the execution of Test setup code into the TestInitialization method of your test class, thus standardizing it.  Just a thought.